# Django ValidationError Doesn't Show Up

Tags: django

I am learning a django and I was practicing registration. But before doing that, I wanted to test the validationerrors but it doesn't show up the error message on the screen even if the form is not valid. I want my program to write on screen an error message when student_tc and student_password don't match.

views.py

```
messages = []
def student_register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = StudentRegisterForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        student_name = form.cleaned_data.get('student_name')
        student_surname = form.cleaned_data.get('student_surname')
        student_no = form.cleaned_data.get('student_no')
        student_contact = form.cleaned_data.get('student_contact')
        student_email = form.cleaned_data.get('student_email')
        student_tc = form.cleaned_data.get('student_tc')
        student_gender = form.cleaned_data.get['student_gender']
        student_branch = form.cleaned_data.get('student_branch')
        student_password = form.cleaned_data.get('student_password')
        data = {'student_name': student_name, 'student_surname': student_surname, 'student_no': student_no,
                'student_contact': student_contact, 'student_email': student_email, 'student_tc': student_tc,
                'student_gender': student_gender, 'student_branch': student_branch,
                'student_password': student_password}
        messages.append(data)
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'student_registered.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'student_register.html', context={'form': form})
form = StudentRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'student_register.html', context={'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class StudentRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['student_name', 'student_surname', 'student_tc', 'student_gender', 'student_no', 'student_contact',
              'student_email', 'student_branch',
              'student_password']
    widget = {'student_password': PasswordInput}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StudentRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}

def clean(self):
    student_password = self.cleaned_data.get('student_password')
    student_tc = self.cleaned_data.get('student_tc')
    if student_password != student_tc:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Password and TC don't match')
    return student_password

def clean_email(self):
    student_email = self.cleaned_data.get('student_email')
    student_email = student_email.lower()
    if User.objects.filter(student_email=student_email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('This e-mail exists')
    return student_email
```

template

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-m-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <h1 class="page-header">Student Registration</h1>
    <br>
    <form action="{% url 'student_register' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                    {{ field }}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <span class="text-danger"><b>{{ error }}</b></span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                        <span class="text-success"><b>{{ field.help_text }}</b></span>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `add_error` to add the error and attach it to a specific field, like `student_password`, then return all the form data, not just 1 value.

Here's an example from a signup form I've got;

```py
    def clean(self):
        """ Provide email match validation """
        super().clean()

        if settings.ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_EMAIL_ENTER_TWICE \
                and "email" in self.cleaned_data \
                and "email2" in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data["email"] \
                    != self.cleaned_data["email2"]:
                self.add_error(
                    'email2',
                    _("You must type the same email each time.")
                )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

A quote from the documentation on this matter;

> Note that any errors raised by your `Form.clean()` override will not be associated with any field in particular. They go into a special “field” (called `__all__`), which you can access via the `non_field_errors()` method if you need to. If you want to attach errors to a specific field in the form, you need to call `add_error()`.

Further reading on [form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/)